# How to determine whether a sequence converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

For this question, I know this sequence converges, but I'm not sure how to get to the final answer. Here is what I have so far, can anyone please help me out?

Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges.

$\left\{\dfrac{1}{2^n} -3\right\}$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{2^n} -3\right) = -3$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

Choose N  $ \geq 0$

Suppose $n>N$

$\left|\dfrac{1}{2^n} -3 -(-3)\right| < \epsilon$

$\left|\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right| < \epsilon$

$\dfrac{1}{2^n} < \dfrac{1}{2^N}$

Comment: do you want to prove by definition?

Comment: once we fix $\epsilon$ then we find $N$ such that...

Comment: At a high-school level this may be good enough for part marks, and perhaps also at a professional level,  because the pro can look at it & say "I know what you mean."  But it is better to write in complete sentences, especially explaining the connection between the lines. Your are less likely to err, and will help in your own insight. You  omitted saying that you choose $N$ large enough that $1/2^n<\epsilon.$

Comment: I wanted to try to do the computation first and then pick the N.

Comment: @dg123 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

From here we obtain

$$\left|\frac{1}{2^n}\right| < \epsilon\iff 2^n>\frac1{\epsilon}\iff n>\log_2\frac1{\epsilon}\implies n>N=\lceil\log_2\frac1{\epsilon}\rceil$$

Comment: Ok so N would be $ln(\frac{1}{\epsilon})?$

Comment: @dg123 More precisely is the first natural $>\ln(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ which is not necessesarly integer. Note indeed that I've used the ceiling symbol, but it is almost a detail here.

Comment: Do you mean n when you say first natural?

Comment: Also what happened to the 2?

Comment: Why did the 2 disappear?

Comment: @dg123 I mean that $\ln(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ is not integer thus if we want explicitely fix an integer bound for n we can set it as $n>N=\lceil\log\frac1{\epsilon}\rceil$ but also simply $n>\log\frac1{\epsilon}$ is ok.

Comment: @dg123 I've assumed $log_2$ of course but we can also adapt to $log_e$.

Comment: @dg123 I've edited clarifying thus point!

Comment: So we can use $ln(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$?

Comment: @dg123 Yes of course, in this case we have $$\left|\frac{1}{2^n}\right| < \epsilon\iff 2^n>\frac1{\epsilon}\iff n\log 2>\log \frac1{\epsilon}\implies n>N=\lceil\frac1{\log 2}\log \frac1{\epsilon}\rceil$$

Comment: How would this question change if say the sequence was $(-2)^n + pi

Comment: @dg123 $(-2)^n$ doesn't converge, we can prove considering two subsequences with different limits  $(-2)^{2k}\to +\infty$ and $(-2)^{2k+1}\to -\infty$